# Process Model Delta

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE.

Sometimes, after I make some alterations to the code and try to run, I get "'Process Model Delta'  has encountered a problem" error. If I try to run again, sometimes it runs (without giving any error again) or again gives the error and I have to restart Eclipse.

I am not pasting any piece of code here, because the code was perfectly fine in many situations when this error occurred.

Can anybody let me know the reason why this error occurs or what is the meaning of this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're actually debug. It that's the case, the cause is in one of your breakpoints. See if it runs fine with breakpoints disabled. If that helps, try Debug view menu Java > Show System Threads.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Hey,
Thanks Max! 
I thought that it could be because of breakpoints, but I was not sure. I will try with breakpoints disabled.